# Problemas al retornar valor de una funcion

Tags: php

Tengo una función dentro de otra función la cual esta dentro de una clase en `PHP`,  la `funcion1` recibe el parámetro de un `query $row['fila1'];` que asigne a una variable **$idgasto.**

Al imprimir **$idgasto** dentro de la función me manda el valor de dicha consulta pero al querer utilizar el valor fuera de la función me lo manda como 1 o 0 el cual no me sirve.

```
function insert($idgasto){ 
   $idgasto1=($idgasto*1);//lo convierto a entero
   echo $idgasto1;//se imprime el valor con exito
   return $idgasto1;
}
```

cuando mando a llamar la función y quiero utilizar el valor de `$idgasto`
solo me manda 0

```
insert();
echo $idgasto;//me imprime 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto:

```
function insert($idgasto){ 
$idgasto1=($idgasto*1);//lo convierto a entero
echo "imprimo dentro de la funcion " . $idgasto1;//se imprime el valor con exito
return $idgasto1;
}
```

Cuando llames a la función, hazlo de esta manera.

```
$variable_de_funcion = 2;
$idgasto = insert($variable_de_funcion);
echo "imprimo fuera de la funcion " . $idgasto;
```

El problema radica en que la variable $idgasto, que muestras fuera de la función, esta fuera del scope de esta, por tanto no cogerá el valor que recibió dentro de la función.